How do I install pycairo using pip into python environment under MSYS2 on Windows 10
I am trying to install pycairo into a python virtual environment under MSYS2 on Windows 10 and following the command: pip install pycairo I get the following error:

$ pip3 install pycairo
Collecting pycairo
Using cached pycairo-1.26.1.tar.gz (346 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [5 lines of output]
running egg_info
writing pycairo.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to pycairo.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to pycairo.egg-info/top_level.txt
error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

Other packages install without problems (e.g. webcolors).
How can I get this to work?
I tried other versions of pycairo unsuccessfully
I have it installed outside of the virtual environment (i.e. through MSYS pacman)

Please what's your Python version?

Python version 3.12
